# Jquery .each() only works on 1 element

Tags: jquery, each

I would like to remove the last 5 chars on a price on the `administrate-price` class. This is only working on 1 element as I can see in my console.

```
$(".administrate-price").each(function(i, object) {
    thePrice = $(this).text();
});
thePrice = thePrice.substr(0, thePrice.length - 5);
```

How can I make this work for all the `administrate-price` elements?

Comment: Please post a complete code example. Here we need at least the HTML as well. Also, shouldn't the last line you posted be within your each function?

Comment: You're setting `thePrice` *outside* the loop

Comment: You're re-assigning the variable each time. It will only contain the last value. So if you have 3, `thePrice` will only be the text of the 3rd object.

Answer (score 3):

By the time the `each` iterations have completed, `thePrice` is set to the text of the last element. Do the `substring` operation within the iteration itself

```
$(".administrate-price").each(function(i, object) {
         var thePrice = $(this).text();
         $(this).text(thePrice.substr(0, thePrice.length-5));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand your building blocks better.

The jQuery `.each(fn)` method is available on any jQuery collection and applies the function `fn` synchronously to each of the elements of the collection with the numerical index of the element.

Your code therefore says:

1. Get all elements with the `administrate-price` class.
2. For each of them: set the global variable `thePrice` to the inner text of the element.
3. Once the loop has completed: set the global variable `thePrice` to its substring lacking the last 5 characters.

Step 2 repeatedly clobbers the value that you're setting the global variable to, such that only the last one is kept. By itself the code snippet that you've given does nothing else; it just clobbers a global variable that you can later see with `window.thePrice` (on a browser).

Instead you probably wanted this:

1. Get all elements with the `administrate-price` class.
2. For each of them:

   - Get the current text.
   - Truncate that text.
   - Set the current text to be the above truncation.

The function (encapsulating step 2) therefore needs to be:

```
function () { 
    var el = $(this);
    el.text( // setter
        el.text() // getter
          .slice(0, -5) // truncation
    );
}
```

This defines one local variable `el` which saves the `$(this)` so that jQuery does not need to build two one-element collections but just reuses one as the getter and setter; you could also just write the one-liner `function(){$(this).text($(this).text().slice(0, -5))}` if you wanted, without storing this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're setting the `thePrice` value *outside* of the loop, after the loop completes. This means that it will only ever see the value of the final iteration. Try this:

```
$(".administrate-price").each(function(i, object) {
    thePrice = $(this).text().substr(0, thePrice.length - 5);
    $(this).text(thePrice);
});
```

It's also worth noting that you do not need to use `each()` in this instance, as you can provide a function to `text()` to be executed against each element individually. Try this:

```
$(".administrate-price").text(function(i, t) {
    return t.substr(0, t.length - 5);
});
```

Comment: oh yeah, forgot about the callback approach! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Don't forget to accept an answer.